# mac m1 error when using sudo in terminal to execute java

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables, macos-monterey

I have this problem in mac when trying to run a mvn command as admin by using sudo i am getting this error :

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

yet when i execute the command without sudo its working fine.
the same its happening when using java in the terminal, using something as simple as java -version its returning the same error when using sudo. But working fine without using  sudo.

can someone give me a hit or explain why is happening ?.

when using sudo to retrieve $JAVA_HOME variable its working fine its returning its path

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/8/jdk8/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Can you execute the java executable directly. Ie. `sudo /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/8/jdk8/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version` I might not have the bin/java bits correct as I don't have osx handy to check.

Answer (score 2):

If it works with as a normal user, it has nothing to do with the platform/CPU. It cannot find the Java executable since it is not on the `PATH`.

You need to preserve the environment, use `sudo -E` for that.

`sudo -E java -version`

The full documentation to the BSD sudo command can be found [here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sudo&sektion=8&format=html):

> -E, --preserve-env - Indicates to the security policy that
> the user  wishes to preserve their existing environment
> variables.
> The security       policy may return an error if the user does not have
> permission to preserve the environment.

Comment: Just tested it right now and it works, thanks for the answer and for the link to the documentation.